# vba macro iteration through outlook tasks not working in new object library (12 vs 15)

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Edit: working solution at the bottom

my colleague got her office updated to 365 which holds 2013 version. Macro that has been working in 2007 without issues do not work now. Probably some changes in object libraries 12 vs 15 that I'm not aware off.

Here's the code below. I get Application_defined or object-defined error on line:

```
Worksheets("ActiveTasks").Cells(rowNo, Column_title).Value = eItem
```

Through trial and error I found that something is wrong with "eItem". I tried defining as Outlook.TaskItem, remove bind overall, refocus worksheet. All worked fine in 2007 excel, but still get object error in 2013 version.

```
Sub Extract_tasks_SPP()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim applOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim nsOutlook As Outlook.Namespace
Dim eFolder As Outlook.folder
Dim eItems As Outlook.Items
Dim eItem As Object
Dim eResItems As Outlook.Items
Dim strCriteria As String

Worksheets("ActiveTasks").Range("A:B").ClearContents

Set applOutlook = New Outlook.Application
Set nsOutlook = applOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
nsOutlook.Logon
Set Recip = nsOutlook.CreateRecipient("InboxName")
Set SharedFolder = nsOutlook.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recip, olFolderTasks)


Set eFolderSPP = SharedFolder
Set eItemsSPP = eFolderSPP.Items

If eItemsSPP.Count < 1 Then
    MsgBox "No Task Items Returned"
Exit Sub
End If
rowNo = 1
Column_title = 1
For Each eItem In eItemsSPP
    Worksheets("ActiveTasks").Cells(rowNo, Column_title).Value = eItem ' I get object defined error on this line. I believe it is eItem that is causing issue
    rowNo = rowNo + 1
Next


Set applOutlook = Nothing
Set nsOutlook = Nothing
Set eFolderSPP = Nothing
Set eItemsSPP = Nothing
Set eResItemsSPP = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Opps, something went wrong. Script will exit"
    End
End Sub
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Solution was setting object property for eItem:

`Worksheets("ActiveTasks").Cells(rowNo, Column_title).Value = eItem.Subject`

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked in VBA, and I've never worked in Office 365, but I remember having a similar problem where I had to go the Tools menu, then select References. That should open a window where you can then choose to add the Object Library from older versions.

Comment: that could probably work, but I was hoping to find solution compatible with new library. Once the move is done to new system, old library will not be needed.

Comment: If you're working with tasks then maybe if you Dim eItem as an Outlook.TaskItem?

Comment: hi Ryan. thanks for the suggestion, but as I mentioned in the post, it was one of first things i tried :). It really is a mystery. File is full of macros that all work fine, apart this one.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot you said you tried that. One last idea then I'll leave you alone :). When I search your error I see it come up most in reference to a failure to send mail. The solution for that problem, not necessarily yours, is to ensure that Outlook is actually open. So ' Shell "Outlook.exe"  ' to open, do your work, then close with ' Shell "taskkill /IM Outlook.exe" '

Comment: Hi Ryan. No problem. Outlook is connected.

I have tried Option explicit statement. I have declared all variables but that does not make any difference - it still executes up to that line.

I think something is wrong in this loop:

For Each eItem In eItemsSPP

I know that statement If eItemsSPP.Count < 1 is valid as it returns number of tasks in the email, but for some reason when I try to loop through each item and write it to the cell it gets stuck.

Unfortunately I can'd do extensive testing as I do not have new office 365 on my pc yet.

Comment: I got the solution. It was basically just adding property to the object which I guess was assigned by default in 2007. Thanks again for all support. I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was setting object property for eItem:

Worksheets("ActiveTasks").Cells(rowNo, Column_title).Value = eItem.Subject